how to make baseline profile for Views system
The test scenario waiting for a splash screen to finish, scrolling through a RecyclerView, and clicking on a random item within it. Your XML layout includes a CollapsingToolbarLayout and a RecyclerView named mainAdsRecyclerView, which seems to contain advertisement items.
Your UI test class BaselineProfileGenerator contains methods for each step of the test scenario:

waitSplashScreenFinish: Waits for the appearance of the toolbar_layout, which indicates the splash screen is finished.
scrollThroughToolbarLayout: Scrolls through the CollapsingToolbarLayout.
waitForAsyncContent: Waits for the appearance of the mainAdsRecyclerView and its content.
scrollThroughMainAdsRecyclerView: Scrolls through the RecyclerView.
goToMainAdDetailJourney: Clicks on a random item within mainAdsRecyclerView.

This setup seems comprehensive, covering the waiting period, scrolling actions, and interaction with the RecyclerView. However, if you encounter any issues or need further assistance, feel free to ask!
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/mainAdsRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="120dp"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:listitem="@layout/row_ad"
                tools:visibility="gone" />

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class BaselineProfileGenerator {

    @get:Rule
    val rule = BaselineProfileRule()

    @Test
    fun generate() {
        rule.collect("com.camelan") {
            pressHome()
            startActivityAndWait()

            // Ensure the activity is fully loaded
            device.waitForIdle(10_000)

            waitSplashScreenFinish()
            scrollThroughToolbarLayout()
            waitForAsyncContent()
            scrollThroughMainAdsRecyclerView()
            goToMainAdDetailJourney()
        }
    }
}

fun MacrobenchmarkScope.waitSplashScreenFinish() {
    val timeout = 15_000L // Increase timeout to 15 seconds for more robustness
    Log.d("BaselineProfileGenerator", "Waiting for toolbar_layout to appear")
    if (!device.wait(Until.hasObject(By.res("com.camelan.main:id/toolbar_layout")), timeout)) {
        Log.e("BaselineProfileGenerator", "toolbar_layout did not appear within the timeout")
        throw IllegalStateException("toolbar_layout did not appear within the timeout")
    }
    Log.d("BaselineProfileGenerator", "toolbar_layout appeared")
}

fun MacrobenchmarkScope.scrollThroughToolbarLayout() {
    val toolbarLayout = UiScrollable(UiSelector().resourceId("com.camelan.main:id/toolbar_layout"))
    toolbarLayout.flingToEnd(10)
    device.waitForIdle()
}

fun MacrobenchmarkScope.waitForAsyncContent() {
    val timeout = 15_000L // Increase timeout to 15 seconds for more robustness
    Log.d("BaselineProfileGenerator", "Waiting for mainAdsRecyclerView to appear")
    if (device.wait(Until.hasObject(By.res("com.camelan.main:id/mainAdsRecyclerView")), timeout)) {
        val contentList = device.findObject(By.res("com.camelan.main:id/mainAdsRecyclerView"))
        if (contentList != null) {
            if (!contentList.wait(
                    Until.hasObject(By.res("com.camelan.main:id/ad_item")),
                    timeout
                )
            ) {
                Log.e("BaselineProfileGenerator", "No ad items appeared within the timeout")
                throw IllegalStateException("No ad items appeared within the timeout")
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("BaselineProfileGenerator", "mainAdsRecyclerView not found")
            throw IllegalStateException("mainAdsRecyclerView not found")
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("BaselineProfileGenerator", "mainAdsRecyclerView did not appear within the timeout")
        throw IllegalStateException("mainAdsRecyclerView did not appear within the timeout")
    }
    Log.d("BaselineProfileGenerator", "mainAdsRecyclerView appeared")
}

fun MacrobenchmarkScope.scrollThroughMainAdsRecyclerView() {
    val mainAdsRecyclerView =
        UiScrollable(UiSelector().resourceId("com.camelan.main:id/mainAdsRecyclerView"))
    mainAdsRecyclerView.flingToEnd(10)
    device.waitForIdle()
}

fun MacrobenchmarkScope.goToMainAdDetailJourney() {
    val mainAdsRecyclerView = device.findObject(By.res("com.camelan.main:id/mainAdsRecyclerView"))
    if (mainAdsRecyclerView != null) {
        val ads = mainAdsRecyclerView.findObjects(By.res("com.camelan.main:id/ad_item"))
        if (ads.isNotEmpty()) {
            val index = (iteration ?: 0) % ads.size
            ads[index].click()
            device.wait(Until.gone(By.res("com.camelan.main:id/mainAdsRecyclerView")), 5_000)
        } else {
            Log.e("BaselineProfileGenerator", "No ads found in mainAdsRecyclerView")
            throw IllegalStateException("No ads found in mainAdsRecyclerView")
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("BaselineProfileGenerator", "mainAdsRecyclerView not found")
        throw IllegalStateException("mainAdsRecyclerView not found")
    }
}

